# Sufficiently accurate descriptions of the standard model suitable for high school children?

Tags: standard-model, education

Is anyone aware of any currently  available learning material suitable for young ages (say around 12-14) that is an accurate enough representation of the standard model, to illustrate at least a significant part of the "quantum weirdness" that physicists have accepted for the past few decades?

For example, I discovered
[an effort to teach a modern particle model from 2017](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6552/aa6cfe), but I am not qualified to judge how much of the modern understanding it conveys.

I am not questioning why the Bohr model is currently being taught as [in this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/488908/why-bohr-atom-model-is-still-being-tought-in-high-school) and would not like to get into an opinionated discussion of whether such material would be useful or not, just looking for any pointers to existing material.

Comment: I haven't read the entire article you linked to by Wiener et al, but the 10 concepts on page 3 are spot on. That's about the level I would attempt to reach with 12-14 year olds. And the language is very carefully chosen, for example concept 8: "In the orbital-space, it is likely to find electrons." hints at the fact that due to the uncertainty principle the electron does not have a definite position.

Comment: Do you mean the standard model of elementary particles?

Comment: Why are you worried about "modern understanding" for something that's only 5 years old? What do you think has changed in that time that's going to matter to the task at hand? Seems to me like you might be missing the forest for the trees there.

Comment: @DKNguyen I said I don't want to get into opinions about the why. But to clarify the question, the ask isn't to represent high level consensus of the last 5 years, but at a minimum the last 50. I am 45 years old and I hadn't heard about entanglement even during my first two years as a physics major in college. The gap between what is understood and what is being taught is enormous.

Comment: @ChristopherAkritidis Read what I wrote again. It's not saying what you seem to think it's saying. It's pointing out you're splitting hairs over the resource you did find unless I misinterpreted what you wanted to say there. From my point of view not much seems to have changed in the last 15 years.

Comment: @DKNguyen I said I am not qualified to judge if the particular resource fits the criterion of a sufficiently accurate representation that illustrates some of the "weirdness" that most people outside the field are oblivious to. The answer could be that it's exactly what am looking for.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder yes, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model

Comment: @ChristopherAkritidis I would ignore the quantum weirdness most people outside the field are oblivious to and just focus on illustrating the path to the quantum weirdness the public is aware of (which seems to be what your original question was seeking anyways). Things like super-position, uncertainty, particle-wave duality and entanglement. Everyone has heard of those and they make zero sense. That's plenty I think.

Comment: @DKNguyen I laughed hard with this last comment. I wish I could upvote it! I would consider it a sufficient answer actually.

Comment: In my country “high school” students are 15-18, not 12-14.

Comment: @G.Smith You're first introduced to atoms and stuff in junior though though.

Comment: Even if you do not want comments about the usefulness of such material, I cannot avoid saying that proposing such material to 12-14 years old children is the worst service one can do to Science and scientific method.  Moreover, even if written by people at CERN, the paper you refer contains serious misconceptions.

Comment: @GiorgioP do you mean the paper oversimplifies to the extent of presenting inaccurate information as facts? As to the other point, I don't know what it's like in the US, but we were introduced to the wondrous world of atoms and molecules very early, but in a purely classical and therefore quite inaccurate way. I really don't want to go into opinions, but I think we underestimate the capacity of children to accept ideas that adults have difficulty wrapping their heads around. Of course I am talking about not showing any equations at all.