# Bohr hydrogen atom model and quantum mechanics on quantisation of angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics

Bohr's model says that angular momentum is quantised to integral multiples of reduced Planck's constant, $$L = nh/2\pi$$
but in quantum mechanics, angular momentum operator has non-integer eigenvalues, since $$L = \sqrt{\ell(\ell+1)} h/2\pi$$
Does that mean Bohr's postulate about angular momentum is wrong?

Comment: near duplicate of [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/395829/36194)

Comment: Bohr's model is completely wrong, but so is the idea that the angular momentum of a system is what matters. What matters is the change of angular momentum because the electromagnetic field can only absorb quanta of energy with angular momenta in multiples of Planck units, which means that atoms can only emit (or absorb) "full photons". Ontologically quantum mechanics won't become a fully self-consistent theory until you are studying quantum field theory (in which "an excited atom" is also merely a semi-stable state of the free field).

Comment: Indeed, some of the angular momentum features of the Bohr model are flat wrong. In phase-space quantization [however](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner–Weyl_transform#The_Weyl_quantization_of_polynomial_observables), several of the mismatches with conventional QM can be explained and rectified, but this outranges your scope. For your purposes, the model is an inspirational departure from classical mechanics.

Comment: There is angular momentum in a particular direction and a square of angular momentum. Bohr did not know it when he formulated his atomic model, but any modern learner of QM must know.

Comment: The assumption of Bohr is correct for the expection value of L along a choosen axis, this simple quantization was sufficient to obtain the correct energied for the Hydrogen atom. All the commponents of L are useless because only one can be measured and the eigeinvalue of L is used for more complicated purposes (than H atom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. Bohr's model is very lucky and very difficult to get working!

For example, while most people only know that Bohr's model give the correct energy levels if we assume that the angular momentum is quantised to $L=n\hslash$, that is only for the case of spherical coördinates.

If we do the Bohr's model in other coördinate systems, we might need to have $L=\sqrt3\hbar$ or some other nonsense like that.

So, there were obvious red flags that Bohr's model is not everything even during its heyday, the old quantum theory period. Modern quantum theory completely changed that and made everything much more internally consistent.

Note: The name of the quantisation is Bohr-Sommerfeld quantisation conditions, not Bohr's model. Of course, just use modern quantum theory.

Comment: is this really true that the outcome of quantizing angular momentum is coordinate dependent?  $L$ is indeed always a multiple of $\hbar$ in the sense that the angular quantum number $\ell$ is always an integer (ignoring spin for the moment),and I've never seen it argued that using Cartesian or cylindrical coordinates changes this to some irrational number.

Comment: By Bohr's model, you need irrational numbers if you pick some confocal coördinates, just to get the energy levels correct. Schrödinger's does not seem to have this issue, IIRC. And no, even if $\ell$ is integer, the eigenvalue of $\sqrt{L^2}$ is $\sqrt{\ell(\ell+1)}$ which is irrational.

Comment: well... I suppose if you think of $L$ as $\sqrt{\ell(\ell+1)}$ then fair but in Bohr's model $L$ is more like $\ell$, which is always an integer.  I will look up the point on confocal coordinates: it's not intuitive why this should depend on the choice of coordinate system.

Comment: It was so weird that even the pioneers who found this behaviour were confused about it. But then modern quantum theory came along and the problem went away.